# Install php5 alongside with php7

Tags: php, php7, php-fpm

I am on `php7` now but I have a legacy program relies on `php5` as it is using `mysql` instead of `mysqli`.

Can I have `php5` installed alongside with `php7` and switch them around when either of them is needed?

Comment: What  about updating your program? Obviously that depends on the complexity of your program. I was able to update mine in a relatively short  period of time, but then my program is very simple.

Comment: @SteveR.  im trying to now. It is modx - can't believe this program is worse than wordpress!

Comment: You may want to look here:  "PHP 7.0 (and 5.6) on Ubuntu"   https://lornajane.net/posts/2016/php-7-0-and-5-6-on-ubuntu  Since I do not have this dual configuration, I have no knowledge of how good the advice is.

Answer (score 5):

I know this post has been here for a long time but I would answer anyway.

You can install `php5` alongside.

All you need to do is install `php5`.

After installing it, you would have multiple folders holding the different version of your php version.

1. First start by adding Ondřej Surý PPA to install different versions of PHP – PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 on Ubuntu system.

   ```
   sudo apt install python-software-properties

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

   ##For Apache Web Server
   sudo apt install php5.6
   ```

   Now you can install most required PHP modules from the list.
2. Install PHP Modules

   ```
   sudo apt install php5.6-cli php5.6-xml php5.6-mysql
   ```
3. To switch between the versions

   1. First make sure you stop your apache2 service

      ```
      sudo service apache2 stop
      sudo a2dismod php7
      ```
   2. I would suggest you run `phpinfo()` after the above steps to confirm the version running on your computer, if all went well, you should most likely get an error, as no php file would run.
   3. Enable e.g. `php5.6`

      ```
      sudo a2enmod php5.6
      ```
   4. Restart your apache2 service

      ```
      sudo service apache2 start
      ```
   5. check php version

      ```
      php -v
      ```